# Efficient set all function

Tags: implementation

A question i have been ask in a **work interview**:

There are 3 simple functions:

- `get(index)` - returns value
- `set(index, value)`
- `setAll(value)` - sets all indexes with value

The first 2 functions are easy for implementation in O(1) time complexity.

The obvious way to implement the third one is to pass each index in O(n) time complexity.

**How can I implement `setAll` in a more efficient way?**

Comment: What language are you using?  Or is this to be language independent?  Java has an Arrays.fill that you can look at. However, I believe it works as a loop as well.  I'm not sure there is a way to set a data set with data faster than O(n) unless you consider something C which supports memset()

Comment: Language does not matter..